# Can I change customer email without entering password on account edit page?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I'm developing a website that contain SSO customers. They do **NOT** have customer password when creating customer account. That caused a problem in a scenario: If they attempt to change email, they need to enter current password.

But as I said before, they do not have customer password, so they simply can't edit their email currently. Every time they try the change email, it shows the error message "**The password doesn't match this account.**". So, is there any methods to change the email address without entering customer password?

Comment: The solution above does not work. The Plugins which are used before will only works with public methods. In this case, Use a alternate route and remove password check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You this you to need customize `EditPost` controller class below file:

```
Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost
```

In excute method below function check if email change request is sent or not

```
// whether a customer enabled change email option
$this->processChangeEmailRequest($currentCustomerDataObject);
```

In `processChangeEmailRequest` function there is check for Password check.

```
/**
 * Process change email request
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerDataObject
 * @return void
 * @throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException
 * @throws UserLockedException
 */
private function processChangeEmailRequest(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerDataObject)
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_email')) {
        // authenticate user for changing email
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate(
                $currentCustomerDataObject->getId(),
                $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password')
            );
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('The password doesn\'t match this account.'));
        }
    }
}
```

You can disable this function call `processChangeEmailRequest` by creating Around event plugin for `EditPost` controller.

Comment: I'm so sorry that due to changed requirement, I don't need to do this task. But I'll still test your answer when I have time, thanks very much!